# how to create multiple files base on the content of file1 in unix? line1 of file1 to newfile1 line2 of file1 to newfile2 etc etc

Tags: unix

i want to read the content of file1.txt and 4 new files
example:
file1.txt contains 10 lines
newfile 1 will contain line 1, 5, 9
newfile 2 will contain line 2, 6, 10
newfile 3 will contain line 3, 7
newfile 3 will contain line 4, 8

file1.txt contains
sr0_dmd_029.dat
sr0_dmd_124.dat
sr0_dmd_185.dat
sr0_dmd_035.dat
sr0_dmd_021.dat
sr0_dmd_072.dat
sr0_dmd_032.dat
sr0_dmd_019.dat
sr0_dmd_042.dat
sr0_dmd_154.dat

expected output:
newfile1.txt
sr0_dmd_029.dat
sr0_dmd_021.dat
sr0_dmd_042.dat

newfile2.txt
sr0_dmd_124.dat
sr0_dmd_072.dat
sr0_dmd_154.dat

newfile3.txt
sr0_dmd_185.dat
sr0_dmd_032.dat

newfile4.txt
sr0_dmd_035.dat
sr0_dmd_019.dat